# Make asp.net table content flush

Tags: html, asp.net, tabular

I am developing a progress bar using a table, I have a cell inside a row containing an image; which I change the width of on a button click.

The problem is, is that the image is not flush with the roof of the table, meaning that you can still see the background when the bar is showing.

My question is, is how do I make a row/cell fill the entire table leaving no padding around the edges?

The code:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellSpacing="0" bgColor="Red" BorderWidth="0px" Height="100px">
    <asp:TableRow BorderWidth="0px" Height="100px">  
        <asp:TableCell Width="200px" BorderWidth="0px" >                
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/ProgressBar.png" Width="0" Height="100" BorderWidth="0px"/>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>  
</asp:Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  This is assuming that your image is 100px high.

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellSpacing="0" BorderWidth="0px">
<asp:TableRow>  
    <asp:TableCell Width="200px" Height="100%" BackColor="Red">                
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/Images/ProgressBar.png" Height="100%"/>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```